# Finding limits for multivariable functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am new to limits of multivariable functions. One of the first thing I learnt is that one of the ways we can evaluate a limit is by plugging in the values so long as it is continuous as per the theorem below.

[image]

I was doing a tutorial question and after I compared my solution to the solution from my professor (pictured below), it seems to me that we find that the function is continuous first and then plug in the values to find the limit.

Why didn’t we have to prove continuity by showing the limit itself equals the function at f(a, b) as the theorem would suggest and why did we just say that since it is continuous on that domain then we can plug it in? How can we say it’s continuous if we didn’t prove it? Does it have to do with the fact that continuity from functions in single variables extends to the same functions which are multivariable?

[image]

I hope someone can clarify this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this function, continuity can essentially be seen the same way that you saw it in single-variable calculus for similar functions.

Polynomial functions such as the inner function within the square root function in your problem are always continuous over $\mathbb{R}$, which was seen in single-variable calculus as well. The square root function that is the 2nd composition in your problem is continuous for any argument $u$ such that $u \in \mathbb{R^+}$. The outermost function in your problem $e^{v}$ is continuous for $v \in \mathbb{R}$. From this alone, it can be seen that $e^{\sqrt{2x-y}}$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R^+}$ via the intersection of the domains of all three functions in the composition.

Starting out with a nonrigorous but somewhat intuitive explanation on why the function can be considered continuous at (3,2) without doing a complete proof:

Let some function $a(x,y)=2x-y$ to represent the innermost function in this problem, $b(u)=\sqrt{u}$ to represent the 2nd function, and $c(v)=e^{v}$ to represent the outermost function. By these definitions, you are now trying to find the continuity of the composition $c \circ b \circ a(x,y)$, which is precisely equal to $e^{\sqrt{2x-y}}$.

Using the coordinates $(3,2)$ given within the limit in the problem, plugging this into the innermost function $a(x,y)$, it can be seen that $a(3,2)=2(3)-2=6-2=4$.

The value of $a(3,2)$ can then be seen to be in the set of $\mathbb{R^+}$, meaning that it is in the domain of the function $b(u)$. Given that $u=2x-y$ and for the ordered pair $(3,2), 2x-y=4$, then $u=4$.

From this, $b(4)=\sqrt{4}=2$. The function of $c(v)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that it is always continuous regardless of any argument value in real numbers. In this case, with $v=b(4)=2$, $c(2)=e^2$.

From this, it can nonrigorously be seen that $e^{\sqrt{2x-y}}$ is continuous at $(3,2)$.

Using an Epsilon-Delta limit proof, it is possible to prove the continuity of $e^{\sqrt{2x-y}}$ rigorously, however the arithmetic for doing this is quite tedious, so it would be suggested to only do this if you need a very rigorous proof to find continuity for your function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Great response!

Answer (score 3):

The key theorems your professor (implicitly) used are these two:
$\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}$

> Let $f,g$ be continuous functions where the range of $f$ is inside the domain of $g$.
> Then $g\circ f$ is continuous.

> Let $f,g:A\to\real$ be continuous functions, where $A\subseteq\real^n$.
> Then $f+g$ and $fg$ are continuous.

I'll leave the proofs to you as a good beginner exercise (not much difference than the 1D case!).
Now, back to your function $f(x,y)=\exp(\sqrt{2x-y})$.
We can deconstruct it step by step.

1. The function $\real^2\to\real$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto x$ is continuous.
   The same is true for $(x,y)\mapsto y$.
   The constant functions $(x,y)\to k$ for any $k\in\real$ are also continuous.
   These can be proved from definitions.
2. By the second theorem above, $(x,y)\mapsto 2x-y$ is continuous.
3. The function $\sqrt{\cdot}:\real_{\ge 0}\to\real$ is continuous, so $(x,y)\mapsto\sqrt{2x-y}$ is continuous, by the first theorem. (We assume the domain is such that $2x-y\ge 0$, or else the function is undefined.)
4. The function $\exp:\real\to\real$ is continuous, so $(x,y)\mapsto\exp(\sqrt{2x-y})$ is continuous, by the first theorem.
   This shows that $f$ is continuous.

Finally, we use the following theorem:

> Let $f:A\to\real$ be a continuous function, where $A\subseteq\real^n$. Let $a\in A$. If $a$ is a limit point of $A$, then
> $$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a).$$

This allows us to "plug in" values into a continuous function to compute its limit at a certain point.
In your case, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(3,2)} f(x,y)=f(3,2)=e^2$.

Comment: @durianicine both explanations really helped me. Thank you so much